# Build an expo project without expo go?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo

so, i m trying to implement '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin' in a react native app working with expo. As the doc of the library says :

> This package cannot be used in the "Expo Go" app because it requires custom native code. However, you can add custom native code to expo by following the guide below.

> Read Expo's "Adding custom native code" guide for detailed information.

I'm usually developing with the expo app, but to develop and test this feature, i'd like to know a way of compiling my app, and directly testing it in my emulator, without 'expo go' ?

As far as i've searched, i've come across :

`npx expo prebuild`
and
`npx react-native run-android --mode="release"`

Is it a good practice ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.